# Check a point if it is in the interior of $T(B)$ or not

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compact-operators

Define the bounded linear operator $T : L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ by
$$Tf(x) = xf(x), \quad \forall f \in L^2[0,1].$$

Let $B$ the open unit ball in $L^2[0,1]$. I need to determine whether $0$ is in the interior of $T(B)$ with respect to metric space $Y = L^2[0,1]$ or not.

Besides, there is a question that I think it may relate to the problem. I also need to prove for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a function $f \in L^2[0,1]$ such that $\| f \|_2 \ge 1$ but $\| Tf \|_2 < \varepsilon$.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I will add my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I have figured out it.

First note that $T$ is injective. Let $V$ be an open set in $X$ containing $0$. Then, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(0,\varepsilon) \subset V$. By the fact, there is a function $f \in L^2[0,1]$ such that $f \notin B(0,1)$ but $T(f) \in B(0,\varepsilon)$. But since $T$ is injective and $f \notin B(0,1)$, $T(f) \notin T(B)$. Therefore we have
$$T(f) \in V \cap Y \setminus T(B),$$
which means the set is nonempty. Hence, $0$ is not in the interior of $T(B)$.

Comment: They key thing that needs to be provided here IMO is to explicitely give an $f \in L^2[0,1]$ that is not in $B(0,1)$ but $T(f) \in B(0,\epsilon)$ Just stating this is IMO just a minor reformulation of the answer that $0$ is not in the interior of $T(B)$.

Comment: @Ingix What do you mean by "IMO"?

Comment: IMO stands for "in my opinion".